# How to connect Meraki L2TP IPSEC VPN from Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, nmcli

I try to connect from my Digital Ocean droplet to my company's L2TP-IPSEC Meraki VPN. I have donwloaded the network-manager-l2tp and already configured it. I try to connect it with this command: `nmcli c up` Meraki But it says:

```
Error: Connection activation failed: Could not find source connection.
```

Please help, how can I fix it?

Comment: I would ask the companies IT department.

Comment: From a linux machine it works perfectly, only in Digital Ocean's droplet appears the failure. So there is no error in my companies VPN server